# Liberar permissão de acesso a tela de gerenciamento do tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, configuração

Tenho instalado o Netbeans 8.1 , nessa instalação, aproveitei de instalar o Tomcat 8.0.27. Porém não estou conseguindo acessar a tela de gerenciamento, pois pede a password.
Já tentei varias configurações de usuario, senha e roles mas sem sucesso, tentei com `usuario: tomcat` e `password : tomcat` e não vai.

```
<tomcat-users>

<user password="admin" roles="manager-script,admin" username="admin"/>
<user username="ide" password="IHyVhSsB" roles="manager-script,admin"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<role rolename="admin-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="admin,admin-gui,manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Comment: Veja a atualização que fiz na resposta.

Answer (score 1):

Sugiro que tente reinstalar seu tomcat ou apagar todas as entradas que você adicionou, pois há muitas alterações nesse seu arquivo `tomcat-users.xml` desnecesssárias. Depois, com o arquivo com as configurações padrões, adicione apenas as linhas abaixo:

```
  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>    
  <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
  <role roleusername="manager-script"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin-gui,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
```

Mais informações podem ser encontradas na [documentação](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Configuring_Manager_Application_Access) do proprio tomcat.